# How do I find an item in a ListView and update another column in that same row?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My app reads a text file and populates a ListView. It's pretty simple, like this:

```
Date     | Invoice   | Status  
20121015 | 123123    |  
20121015 | 123124    | 
20121015 | 123456    |  
20121015 | 124123    |
```

I then need to read a 2nd text file, which may or may not contain an invoice found in the ListView along with a status. If there is a matching invoice, the status from that 2nd text file needs to be added to the ListView so it would look like this:

```
Date     | Invoice   | Status  
20121015 | 123123    |  
20121015 | 123124    | 
20121015 | 123456    | Paid 
20121015 | 124123    |
```

Originally I had a ListBox with only the invoice numbers, and was doing

```
int index = ListBox1.FindString(<whatever>);
```

to get the index of the row containing an invoice, then removing the item (RemoveAt(Index)) and inserting a new item like

```
ListBox.Items.Insert(index, invoice + " PAID")
```

How do I do something similar with a ListView? I like the idea of having columns instead of just 1 line of text. Should I use something other than a ListView to accomplish this?

On average, each text file I'm reading has <1000 rows that need to be added.

Comment: Are you reading both files at the same time? (i.e. one after the other?) maybe you could just read them both and create a list of combined data which you could then use to populate the `ListView`

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't be reading the 2nd file at the time time as the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enumerate through the `Items` collection of your listview. And yes listview is the ideal control for this.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    var invoice = item.SubItems[1];
    if (invoice.Text == "whatever")
    {
        item.SubItems[2] = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() { Text = "Paid" };
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. I figured I was going to have to loop through the items like that!

Comment: Since my "Status" (index 2) column wasn't populated, I got an error with the above code about 2 being an invalid index. I quickly fixed this by putting a "-" in the Status column when I read the first file. Thanks again!